# Rewrite resource URL to serve files from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have a static HTML site that uses **resource tags** (images, css, scripts) as follows:

```
<html>
    <head><title>htaccess test page</title></head>
    <body>
        <img src="/img/img.jpg" alt="...">
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the html file in the browser, the request is made to:

`http://localhost/img/img.jpg` (which understandably returns a 404)

Where as I'd like the request to be made to:

`http://localhost/site/img/img.jpg`

The directory structure is as follows:

```
- www
    - site
        - .htaccess
        - img
            - img.jpg
```

I have been searching for a solution and have a vague idea that `RewriteCond` is the way to go, but I can't get this to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if requested URI is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# serve the file from the img directory, yes, very limited,
# and requires me to add rules for scripts, css etc.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ img/$1 [L]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. SO returns quite a few solutions to this issue but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You solution is going to treat every file in this way and will re rout it. With this **RewriteRule** only images will be redirected to /site/{Path of the image defined in HTML}

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /site/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

You should put images like this `<img src="img/img.jpg" alt="...">`

The final version looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# if requested URI is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# image part
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /site/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, also, I can't change the `<img src="...">` although I do know that changing `src` attribute will fix this issue.

Comment: Putting "/" in start is a bad practice. If this is not your code then it is fine. I have updated the answer and its working for me.